# urllib.urlopen() gives socket error: Name or service not known on python2.7

Tags: linux, python-2.7, urlopen

I am just starting to use and learn Python, so this may seem vary naive to ask. 
On my Linux system if i try to get a webpage using `urllib.urlopen()` I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen  
    return opener.open(url)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open  
    return getattr(self, name)(url)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 344, in open_http  
    h.endheaders(data)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders  
    self._send_output(message_body)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output  
    self.send(msg)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect  
    self.timeout, self.source_address)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection  
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):  
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known  
>>>
```

If I try to do the same in the Python 2.7 installed in my Windows 7 system, it works fine.
Since i am a novice, its difficult for me to diagnose the problem. I tried to research it but still haven't got any answers.

So my questions are:

1. What is different in the windows system that `urlopen()` works there but not on Linux.
2. What needs to be done to ensure that `urlopen()` works on the Linux system. Its necessary   for me that it works since the the program I am developing has some bash   command calls and the program depends extensively on the proper working of `urllib`.

Comment: kindly help since my work is stalled due to this problem.

Comment: is your linux system connected to the internet?

Comment: yes....i can access internet normally with the browser...i can get the same files through the bash command curl...but don't know what seems to be the problem with python.

Comment: well, you're not showing us any code, but there's nothing conceptually particular to `urlopen` on Linux vs. Windows. You need to use `urllib2`, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: There is nothing particular about the code. I used the simple urlopen command i.e. urllib.urlopen("www.wormbase.org"). Do i need to specify something more? This same command works fine on windows.

Comment: Another piece of info is that i access internet through my university server which requires an authentication. On windows, it prompts me to enter the username and password when i give this command and displays the html file. Doesn't happen on the linux system

Comment: well, that's your issue. you're using some kind of proxy that needs to be specified in function call.

Comment: i have got a solution for this, though i would have liked to know the proper solution. I think i will use bash system calls to run the code. Thanks anyways!! :)